# How do I print out an array to screen ? SVG/D3/JS

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a force layout graph and when I click on the nodes a array gets printed out to console.

This list is an array of only the selected nodes. So the list will change depending on what nodes are selected/unselected.

What I wish to do is have a section of the screen which shows this array/list of selected nodes. I want it similar to the console but I need it to update itself, rather than printing the array out every time I click on a node, I need it to just be one list - no duplicates. I am wondering how to do this and how to actually append the lists text to the SVG

--------------------Added code
-HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>Cloud</title>        
            <script type="text/javascript" src="network.json"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" /> 
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>‌​
            <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
            <input id="search">
            <button type="button" onclick="searchNode()">Search</button>
        </div>      
        <svg id="cloud" width="800" height="600" ></svg>        
        <form>
        Orientation
        <select id="myListOrientation" onchange="orientation()">
        <option selected="selected">Force</option>
        <option>Portrait</option>
        <option>Landscape</option>
        </select>       
        </form> 

        <link href="ajs_network1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="ajs_network1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, you don't have to create and show the list in SVG. You can manipulate the DOM outside the visualisation using D3 as well and I suspect that a `ul` element might be the best way to show the list of selected nodes. If you could post an example of what your HTML/JS code looks like, then it would be easier to give a more concrete answer.

Comment: @musically_ut added the HTML code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your JavaScript code, it will be hard to give you the exact answer that will solve your issue, so I'll give you a more generic answer.

**Step 1: Create a div in your html code to contain the array**

```
<div id="arrayStrContainer"></div>
```

**Step 2: On click, put the stringified version of your object in the screen**

```
node = d3.selectAll('g node');
node.on('click', function(d) {
    // console.log(d.arrayAttr) // what you did before
    d3.select('#arrayStrContainer').text(JSON.stringify(d.arrayAttr));
    // this will override whatever was in the div with the new array. 
})
```